# Error: Encoding is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, python-2.x

I keep receiving this error:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.
```

When I run my code:

```
import re

f = open("/home/file/abc.sql", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
source=f.read()

with open("/home/file/samp0l9.sql","w") as output:
    output.write(re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', f, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Any ideas on why that may be? Inside the file is just some text.

Comment: What version of python are you running for this code?

Comment: I'm (almost) sure you are running Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: Ya, your right. I didnt't even notice.

Comment: That explains the problem then.  The builtin `open` function only accepts `encoding` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

Vs:

Python 2.7

```
open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
```